# How to show new data on page after saving AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am putting some names in a form and trying to show them alphabetically after saving. Here is the method which has all the saved data. `response.data` should have all the saved data:

```
function refreshNames() {
   NameService.getNames().then(function(response) {
      $scope.names = _.sortBy(response.data, "bank_name");
         console.log($scope.names);
      });
}
refreshNames(); //this method shows already saved names
```

Here in the saveButton function I am calling the above function and expecting to see the newly saved name with the older names. But it does not show in the list.

```
  $scope.saveButton = function() {
    var name_id = _.pluck($scope.newNames, "NameID");
    ClipMetadataService.saveNames(station_id, $scope.newTemplateFields).then(
                function(response) {
            NameService.getNames().then(function(response) {
               // $scope.names = _.sortBy($scope.names.concat(response.data),
                     "bank_name");// this shows the newly added name in the list, but I am trying to use the refreshNames() method other than doing this
               console.log(response.data);//has the newly added name
               refreshNames();// this method DOES NOT show the newly added name in the list
            });
            };
```

Putting `$scope.names = _.sortBy($scope.names.concat(response.data), "bank_name");` in the `saveButton` method shows the newly added name in the list but I am trying to use `refreshNames()` method to do this. How can I modify the method to add the newly added `response.data`?

Comment: can you post the whole code inside saveButton

Comment: oh dude! you are not saving any new data

Comment: yeah, the response.data is having the new data that I can see, but I am not sure how to save that in `$scope.names`, I am new in using these. so I am really confused about what to do!

Answer (score 1):

No need to make calls in both the methods, separate the functionality. Check the code below:-

```
function refreshNames(data) {
   $scope.names = _.sortBy(response.data, "bank_name");
}

$scope.saveButton = function() {
   NameService.getNames().then(function(response) {
   refreshNames(response.data);// pass the response to the refreshNames method to sort them
   });
};
refreshNames();
```

Comment: `function refreshNames(data)` here do I have to pass `response` other than `data` in the function? and at the end I cannot call `refreshNames()` without passing a parameter inside it, right?

Comment: yes, essentially you'll be calling the saveButton() instead of refreshNames()